# Image caching using HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, http, cache

I found that adding

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:%{HTTP:If-None-Match}]
```

To the bottom of my htaccess file (below all rewriterule) solved my issue (HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE was not being set) with caching dynamic generated images. Brilliant.

Although what does this actually do and why it is needed? 
Is it necessary I have this in every .htaccess or can I change the apache server config so I dont have to add this to every website project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If-modified since is an HTTP packet header ENV variable which basically sets a time in which if a client has visited a server, and the content which the client is requesting has changed then the server will return the changed content, else it will return a 304 not-modified response without the documents content.

Comment: Ok I understand how it works now thanks. How come I need the setting in the .htacces to make this work though? Would this be related to the apache setup or the PHP CMS with rewrite.

Comment: no this is related to php and apache setup, because php cannot access

Comment: the php script is recieving info from apache through the $_SERVER superglobal, the above headers mentioned in your script, are grabbed by php, alternatively instead of apache_request_header